# How can simulation be fast when Electric Field is being measured with probe in CST Microwave Studio?

Tags: electromagnetism

I am measuring the electric field in the closure box with aperture and using probe to achieve that. But I have a problem. When I use the probe for measurement, results are not accurate in transient solver. So, I changed the settings in the transient solver > Specials and I use the program with high number of pulses option ( For example, 100000 and more pulses ). But simulation time is really bad and it takes nearly four days to complete with my desktop pc ( and I know that my pc is not as fast as enough, but this is my situation). How can I drop the simulation time to measuring the E-Field with probe?

Thank you.

Comment: I do not quite understand what exactly it is you are trying to do, but from the title I assume that you are using a very specific piece of software. You are probably better off asking questions of this detail on the mailing lists or in the forums of this software.